# Load and save bitmaps using dotnet

Tags: .net, graphics

This may be simple one, but 5 mins of Googling didn't give me the answer.
How do you save and load bitmaps using .Net librabries?

I have an Image object and I need to save it to disk in some format (preferably png) and load back in later.
A C# example would be great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a really simple example.

**Top of code file**

```
using System.Drawing;
```

**In code**

```
Image test = new Bitmap("picture.bmp");
test.Save("picture.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Remember to give write permissions to the ASPNET user for the folder where the image is to be saved.

Comment: Make sure you have write permissions for ASP.NET on the folder you want to save.

Comment: `Bitmap` is in the `System.Drawing` assembly.

Comment: OK, added it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya, use the Image.Save() method.

A better explanation and code sample than I could provide can be found here:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

About 10 seconds of google lead me to [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) for the save method, you can dig around a bit more for the others.